# Rails routing: Treating hardcoded path as a parameter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to Rails, and after reading some of the Rails Routing documentation, I still can't figure out why my path is being treated as such:

With the following examples, Rails complains that it is unable to find a Movie whose `id` is equal to "inception", even though I am trying to pass along an id parameter.

(*The `controller#action` to which I am routing is of the `resources`-type `show`*).

**routes.rb**

1: `get 'movies/inception' => "movies#show", :id => 6`
2: `get 'movies/inception' => 'movies#show', defaults: {id: 6}`
(These two lines are obviously tried separately.)

**Error**
1:`Couldn't find Movie with id=inception`
2: `app/controllers/movies_controller.rb:16:in`show'
3: `{"id"=>"inception"}`

Why is the `inception`-part of the matched url treated as a variable even when I'm not prefixing it with `:` and how do I make a hardcoded url point to a `object#show`-action with a hardcoded `id`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you taked into issue with routes priority:

Not all routes are created equally. Routes have priority defined by the order of appearance of the routes in the config/routes.rb file. The priority goes from top to bottom. The last route in that file is at the lowest priority and will be applied last. If no route matches, 404 is returned.

So, I suppose, that **you had defined**

```
resources :movies
```

**before**

```
get 'movies/inception' => "movies#show", :id => 6
get 'movies/inception' => 'movies#show', defaults: {id: 6}
```

And your routes were not overwritted.

---

Just see your last question. Uses this route form, instead of yours:

```
get 'movies/inception/(:id)' => 'movies#show', defaults: {id: 6}
```

Comment: I have indeed defined `resources :movies` first. Wouldn't that be necessary as that defines the path that one of the preceding routes point to?

Comment: Nevermind that comment, I am tired. :) It makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you have a line something like

```
 resources :movies
```

If this is the case, then it is creating the standard get show route of movies/:id

If this line is above your hard-coded route then it would take precedence.  The lines at the top of the routes file take precedence over anything below it

A couple of things that may help you on your rails journey.  From the command line, run

```
rake routes
```

That will spit out all available routes

Something you may want to consider if you are looking to do this:
Check out the [friendly_id gem](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id)
"It allows you to create pretty URL’s and work with human-friendly strings as if they were numeric ids for ActiveRecord models." such as /movies/inception

Comment: Cool, up for friendly_id gem